# Blaze does not understand a SQLAlchemy type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, blaze

I am getting errors trying to use blaze

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from blaze import *

database_con = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://server/database?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0", echo=False)

bzdata = data(database_con)
```

> Blaze does not understand a SQLAlchemy type. Blaze provided the
>   following error:  No SQL-datashape match for type TIMESTAMP Skipping.

is there a way to fix this?